# com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-ee, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Push notification in my application while sending push notification from server getting the below exception here is the exception i'm facing

```
om.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl E Couldn't send message after 3 retries.Message(Id=380; Token=35B25C240F90FBFF2CE4F4E57CFCA697B2E1850513BFFCA00A950D315004096D; Payload={"aps":{"alert":{"body":"message%","action-loc-key":null},"sound":"","badge":1},"payload":"{"text"}"})
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection E FPWSE1083E: Failed to send APNS notification with identifier 380, device token: 35B25C240F90FBFF2CE4F4E57CFCA697B2E1850513BFFCA00A950D315004096D
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1979)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1086)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:709)
    at sun.security.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:75)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:302)
    at com.ibm.pushworks.server.notification.apns.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:292)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsPooledConnection$2.run(ApnsPooledConnection.java:47)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

SystemErr                                                    R Exception in thread "pool-6-thread-380" 
SystemErr                                                    R com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_expired
```

checked the certificate in portal not expired same is valid for next 6 months used the same certificate in the server as well.

We are getting the APNS device token.

But still getting the "Certificate_expired" exception. Totally confused.
Can anyone faced this kind of issue?

Comment: The message shows that the current certificate has expired. This is coming out as the SSL exception when MFP server is connecting to APNS.
Which portal shows the certificate's validity? Is it Apple Developer portal ? Also, what does MFP console show?

Comment: I checked in Apple Developer Portal.

Comment: MFP Operations console also shows the expiry. Again the application wlapp. Can you check that also. This handshake failure comes because APNS says the certificate has expired. If nothing works, you might want to create the .p12 again ( exporting the right certs) and try

Comment: MFP console displays certificate is not expired its valid up to Sep 9, 2018.

Comment: Was this working earlier and failed suddenly , or have you not been able to get this working ever? If you have always had the issue , what is the application server you are using and the exact build version of the JDK you are using